# The text does not change from the first click on the button

Tags: java, android

I need that when I click on the button, the text in cenApple changes to i * 132, but when I click on it, countApple becomes 1 more, as it should be, and cenApple remains the same, but if I click on it again, cenApple already changes to i * 132.

```
View.OnClickListener appleListenerPlus = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(countApple.getText().toString());
                countApple.setText(String.valueOf(i + 1));
                i = i;
                int k = (i * 132);
                String a = (String.valueOf(k));
                cenApple.setText(a + " money");
        }
    };
```

Comment: `i = i;` don't see the value in this, using `i k a` as variable names doesn't help anyone else understand your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why do you assigning same value again in this line: `i = i;`. it will stay the same...

when you change text then you should read it again or at least update `i` value also

```
            int i = Integer.parseInt(countApple.getText().toString());
            i++; // increment in here
            countApple.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            // or just read updated value again
            //i = Integer.parseInt(countApple.getText().toString());
            

            int k = (i * 132);
            String a = (String.valueOf(k));
            cenApple.setText(a + " money");
```